# Att what offset does Quarkus Kafka messaging recover after throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms error?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

We got the message that `throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms` was reached and the application stopped consuming. When we looked at the consumer stats, there was no offset/lag. I.e: The list partitions/offsets for that consumer group was empty. We restarted the application and it skipped a bunch of records going to latest offset. And then the consumer offset stats looked normal again as showing partition/offset/lag.

So did the consumer get unregistered after a while because it took too long to restart the application?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the `auto.offset.reset` property, which defaults to `latest`.

The throttled commit strategy doesn't have any effect on this. It just tracks the messages and periodically commits latest offset of processed messages.

`latest` offset reset picks the latest committed offset for a consumer group, if it exists, and if not goes to the tail of the topic-partition.

If your application failed to process successfully the record with the earliest offset (maybe the head of the topic-partition) it can't commit any offsets for the consumer group and the committed offsets would be empty. At restart the app would jump to the tail of the topic.

Comment: We use "latest" as default setting. We got the warning, when we looked at the consumer status, it wasn't there we restarted the app and a whole bunch of record got skipped, so that negates the whole "at-least-once" property. We rebooted many times the application and checked and the offsets where continuing fine. Mind you we rebooted when it was healthy. Does it somehow remove the consumer if maybe we didn't tend to it for too "long" when that warning happens? Also when does it decide to mark itself unhealthy because other times it stop processing and other times it still processing/consuming.